# Horizontally distribute three buttons evenly ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, frame

I have three `UIButtons` and a holder `UIView` I want all my three `UIButton` to be vertically centred inside the `UIView` and also I want them to be distributed equal horizontally

```
float ycentre = CGRectGetMidY(self.buttonHolderView.bounds);
float xposition = (self.buttonHolderView.frame.size.width - 135.0f)/4.0f;


self.button1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xposition,0, 45, 30)];
self.button1.center = CGPointMake(self.button1.frame.origin.x, ycentre);


self.button2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((xposition*2)+45,0, 45, 30)];
self.button2.center = CGPointMake(self.button2.frame.origin.x, ycentre);

self.button3 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((xposition*3)+90,0, 45, 30)];
self.button3.center = CGPointMake(self.button3.frame.origin.x, ycentre);
[self.button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(ShareButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.buttonHolderView addSubview:self.button1];
[self.buttonHolderView addSubview:self.button2];
[self.buttonHolderView addSubview:self.button3];
```

Each button has height 30 and width 45 , but my code doesn't distribute them equally what is wrong?

Comment: post UI what you are looking for...

Answer (score 2):

Place them in a `UIStackView`. It makes spacing views evenly quite easy.

Comment: the best approach. Hail `UIStackView`...! :P

Comment: Note `UIStackView` requires iOS 9.0+

Answer (score 0):

Set the `frame` of your buttons as follows and do Not set `center`

```
float thirdOfWidth = (self.buttonHolderView.frame.width/3.0);
float buttonWidth = 45.0;
float buttonHeight = 30.0;

self.button1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(thirdOfWidth*0 + (thirdOfWidth - buttonWidth)/2, (self.buttonHolderView.frame.height - buttonHeight)/2, 45, 30)];

self.button2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(thirdOfWidth*1 + (thirdOfWidth - buttonWidth)/2, (self.buttonHolderView.frame.height - buttonHeight)/2, 45, 30)];

self.button3 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(thirdOfWidth*2 + (thirdOfWidth - buttonWidth)/2, (self.buttonHolderView.frame.height - buttonHeight)/2, 45, 30)];
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done also in loop with arbitrary count of buttons

```
        NSInteger count = 3;
        CGFloat buttonWidth = 45;
        CGFloat buttonHeight = 30;
        CGFloat x = (self.bounds.size.width - buttonWidth) / 2;
        CGFloat verticalSpacing = ((self.bounds.size.height - buttonHeight * count) / count) - buttonHeight / 2;
        CGFloat y = verticalSpacing;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
            [self addSubview:button];
            y += buttonHeight + verticalSpacing;
        }
```